# libsvn - svn_client_checkout()

Tags: c++, svn, visual-c++

I'm trying to just do a simple checkout.I've got the code I think would work, and I can compile it.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "svn_pools.h"
#include "svn_client.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    svn_error_t *err;
    apr_pool_t *pool;
    svn_client_ctx_t *ctx;

    apr_initialize();
    pool = svn_pool_create( NULL );

    if ( err = svn_client_create_context( &ctx, pool ) )
    {
        svn_pool_destroy( pool );
            return 0;
    }

    err = svn_client_checkout( NULL, "http://tortoisesvn.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/ResText", "C:\\sve", NULL, true, ctx, pool );
    svn_pool_destroy( pool );
    return 0;
}
```

But at run have mistake at function svn_client_checkout(). Access violation when reading 0x00000000. I thunk that I forgot to initialize one of my variables. But what and where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the 4th parameter, `const svn_opt_revision_t *peg_revision`, is not optional and therefore a `NULL` won't do.

Initializing it e.g. like this should work:

```
svn_opt_revision_t rev = {svn_opt_revision_head, 0};
svn_client_checkout(..., "C:\\sve", &rev, true, ...);
```

Refer to the [documentation for `svn_opt_revision_t`](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/api/1.7/structsvn__opt__revision__t.html) for details in what ways you can set and use it.

Comment: So... I tried it in another program and have the the same mistake. But now at this simple test this code to work!!! With this functions:

revision.kind = svn_opt_revision_head;
//svn_opt_revision_t rev = {svn_opt_revision_unspecified, 0};
err = svn_client_checkout( NULL, "http://tortoisesvn.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/ResText", "C:\\sve", &revision, true, ctx, pool );

Sank! But my real programm still doesn't work. Сontinue to deal...

Comment: OK, I'll edit the `svn_opt_revision_head` in, unspecified is apparently bad. -- But how does it not work now? Still crashing with "access violation at 0x00000000"?

Comment: I seem to have found my mistake. svn_client_create_context() I performed elsewhere and then kept "ctx" and passed to a function which served svn_client_checkout(). Then crashing with "access violation at 0x00000000")))

Comment: I think so... Now check=)

Comment: Ok. Mistake in `config` fild if `ctx`. Whitout it programm work. =) Sank for help!